# screen -t <titlename> , does not set screen title properly

Tags: bash, terminal, gnu-screen

I setup `$HOME/root/.screenrc` with

```
caption always "%3n %t%? @%u%?%? [%h]%?%=%c"
```

This is supposed to show the title at the bottom
When I launch a new screen with
`screen -t testtitle`

I see a different title

```
0 root@SERVERNAME:~
```

I can then set the title with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>

Why can't I specify the title when launching screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from the category "It's not a bug, it's a feature!"

The problem is the bash (maybe the same or similar in other shells) variable `PROMPT_COMMAND` which is set by default in your distribution.

This variable is used to communicate with a lower level software (like a terminal emulator) by writing escape sequences (which you do not see because they are caught by `screen`) every time a prompt is created.

I just had a look at `man screen` in order to point you at the relevant parts and noticed that it seems not to be necessary to unset `PROMPT_COMMAND` because this behaviour can be disabled within `screen`:

```
defdynamictitle off
```

That should be enough. You can quickly test for this being the problem by disabling the init files:

```
screen -t testtitle /bin/bash --norc
```

See `man -P 'less -p "^TITLES \(naming windows\)"' screen` for an explanation.

Comment: Thank You, Great answer and explanation.

Comment: @GregLong Then you can accept my answer (which has the advantage that the site users know that this quastion can be considered answered).